# Send one-shot message using SocketCAN

Tags: linux, can-bus, socketcan

Is it possible to send a "one-shot" CAN message using SocketCAN? This is basically a message that does not expect an acknowledgement back from the receiver. The protocol allows this ACK bit not to be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "one-shot", but I send single CAN frames all the time using the `cansend` utility from [can-utils](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils), like this:

```
$ cansend can0 135#02080426A10D112A
```

I've also written C programs that do the same using an `AF_CAN` socket. (You can basically crib from `cansend.c` to figure out how.)

Regarding retransmission of messages, this doesn't happen with `cansend`:

```
$ timeout 20s tcpdump -i can0 -w out.pcap &                                                                                                                                               
[1] 16509
tcpdump: listening on can0, link-type CAN_SOCKETCAN (CAN-bus with SocketCAN headers), capture size 262144 bytes

$ cansend can0 135#02080426A10D112A

$ 1 packet captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

[1]  + 16509 exit 124   timeout 20s tcpdump -i can0 -w out.pcap
```

In the sequence above, there are no consumers online, so nobody ACKs the message, but I *still* only capture a single packet on `can0`. It seems safe to conclude that the SocketCAN stack isn't 'automagically' trying to re-send the message in the background after `cansend` exits.

Comment: If you don't have a receiver to read the message and send ACK back, the sender would keep retrying. I just want to send a message and if there is no one there to read it it would be lost but the sender would move on.

Comment: I updated my answer to note that `cansend` does not attempt to retransmit messages. I've worked quite a bit with CAN, but I'm by no means an expert, so... perhaps I've misunderstood your problem. Can you not shell out to `cansend` (using, e.g., `system()`) to achieve your stated goal?

Comment: No, cansend will not retransmit. That is entirely handled by the CAN controller. What I suppose @ilya1725 is after is the one-shot mode that most CAN controllers are capable of using. E.g. from MCP2515: `One-Shot mode ensures that a message will only
attempt to transmit one time. Normally, if a CAN
message loses arbitration, or is destroyed by an error
frame, the message is retransmitted. With One-Shot
mode enabled, a message will only attempt to transmit
one time, regardless of arbitration loss or error frame.`

Comment: CAN frames that had already reached the peripheral's internal buffer are not captured by Wireshark. I suggest to listen with another device on the bus.

Answer (score 0):

The CAN frame will be retransmitted again and again until a bus error is detected (bus off). This is done by the CAN peripheral (it is part of the [spec](http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/webres/can20.pdf), search for "retransmission"), SocketCan does not know anything about that.

SocketCan allows you to subscribe to different [error notifications](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.14/source/include/uapi/linux/can/error.h) on the bus/controller. In general, CAN peripherals/drivers implement the signaling of a subset of these errors only. If you are lucky, you could be able to [subscribe (see 4.1.2)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt) for notifications and react accordingly.

Comment: Most CAN controllers support a one-shot mode that skips the retransmission. I can see no reason for SocketCan to not be able to support this. In fact, the `ip link set can0 type can help` lists "one-shot" as an available option. However, at least on my hardware this gives me an `Operation not supported` response.

Comment: `Operation not supported` probably menas "your driver and/or hw does not have that option". Anyway, I think you are right and the OP was asking about "one-shot" at the peripheral level, just seems to be confusing comparing OP question against accepted answer. Also, I was not aware of the `one-shot` option in `ip`, thx!

Comment: Thanks @oxuf, I expected this behavior, but couldn't find proof anywhere else.